# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException Occurrs during List.add()

Tags: java, list, exception

I get a weird problem. Getting `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. But I'm not modifying the current collection. Please help.

Method Call

```
setAllAddress((List<AddressBean>) usrProfileResp.getAddressBeanList());
setShippingAddresses(getAllAddress());
```

Methods

```
public List<AddressBean> getAllAddress() {
    return allAddress;
}

public void setShippingAddresses(List<AddressTokenBean> shippingAddresses) {
        shippingAddresses = new ArrayList<AddressBean>();
        List<AddressBean> addresses = getAllAddress();
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) { 
            for (AddressBean addr : addresses) { // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
                if (!Constants.BILLING_ADDRESS.equals(addr.getAddressType())) {                    
                    shippingAddresses.add(addr);                
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is `shippingAddresses` the same instance as `addresses`? Post `getAllAddresses()` and any more relevant code.

Comment: I have added the shipping address init in code. Please check.

Comment: And `getAllAddress()`? It's starting to look like `shippingAddresses` is a class variable and `getAllAddress()` returns it.

Comment: Please show your `getAllAddress()` implementation.

Comment: There must be another thread modifying the collection returned by `getAllAddress()`.

Comment: @hmjd But there is only one main thread.

Comment: @Vanathi, so this is an application that you have completely written and the code is not being deployed in a web server or similar?

Comment: @hmjd yes, it's complete and has been deployed.

Comment: How has it been deployed? Stand alone application or as web application for example?

Comment: Its web application. Oracle ADF application.

Comment: @Vanathi, then it is quite likely the code is running in a multithreaded environment. Even though you don't explicity create any threads in your code, it can be invoked by multiple threads.

Comment: @Vanathi, just wanted to understand why you are passing shippingAddresses as a parameter to setShippingAddresses method when you are anyway re-initializing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explaination is that `addresses` and `shippingAddresses` refer to the same collection.  You can check this in your debugger.

Does getAllAddresses() use shippingAddresses at all?

Are you sure this collection is not being modifed in another thread? Does this happen all the time or only occasionally?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I do initialize `shippingAddresses`. :(

Comment: Not sure what that means, but I assume you are absolutely sure they are not the same object and you have checked in your debugger?

Comment: @Peter..Its obvious..he is creating a new Collection

Comment: Without the source for getAllAdresses() it not obvious.

Comment: @Ahmad obviously there is no bug then. ;)

Comment: @Peter I have done these kind of coding many times. it is weird :(((

Comment: Can you make `shippingAddresses` a local variable and only set the field at the end to ensure it cannot be modified in another thread?

Comment: @Peter, it worked greatly. Can you please explain why the previous one created problem?

Comment: If that worked, it means that the field `shippingAddresses` is being using in the same thread in a method you call, or a different thread. My making it local until you have finished with it, you ignore changes being made elsewhere. (So it doesn't really fix the cause of the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understood why you all guys consider shippingAddresses at all?
Vanathi said that the exception occurs while attempting to iterate over the

> List addresses = getAllAddress();

in the for-each loop.

So there should be a thread that changes the array referenced by  'addresses'.
BTW does the exception happen during the fist iteration or

You implementation of 'getAllAddresses' is as follows:

> public List getAllAddress() {
>       return allAddress;
>   }

So I conclude that 'allAddresses' is just a data member of some class.
This class obviously allows concurrent modification( another thread? )
This is where you should put your efforts... Just IMO :)

Hope this helps